# Some issues with sending List<T> as IEnumerable<T> to a method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface, ienumerable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upcasting and generic lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730401/upcasting-and-generic-lists)

Ok, I want to send a `List<CardHolder>` as an `IEnumerable<ICardHolder>` where `CardHolder : ICardHolder`. However, the compiler errors:

> Error  4   Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

This seems strange to me, considering that an `List<T> : IEnumerable<T>`. What's going wrong?

```
public interface ICardHolder
{
    List<Card> Cards { get; set; } 
}

public class CardHolder : ICardHolder
{
    private List<Card> cards = new List<Card>();
    public List<Card> Cards
    {
        get { return cards; }
        set { cards = value; }
    }

    // ........
}

public class Deck : ICardHolder
{
    // .........

    public void Deal(IEnumerable<ICardHolder> cardHolders)
    {
         // ........
    }

    // .........
}

public class Game
{
    Deck deck = new Deck();
    List<CardHolder> players = new List<CardHolder>();

    // .........

    deck.Deal(players); // Problem is here!

    // .........
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `List<T>` is not a subtype of `IEnumerable<T1>` even if `T : T1`.

Generics in C# (before C# 4.0) are 'invariant' (ie. don't have this sub-typing relationship).  In .Net 4, `IEnumerable<T>` will have its type parameter annotated as being 'covariant'.  This means that `List<T>`  will be a subtype of `IEnumerable<T1>` if `T : T1`.

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233054(VS.100).aspx) on MSDN for more details of this feature.

**Edit** - You can work around this in your case by making the `Deal` method generic:

```
public void Deal<T>(IEnumerable<T> cardHolders) where T : ICardHolder
{
     // ........
}
```

Comment: OK, so I need to convert my List<CardHolder> to List<ICardHolder> to be able to send it as an IEnumerable<ICardHolder>? Oh, and is it possible to get some sort of preview for C# 4.0 on VS2008?

Comment: There an excellent InfoQ article on co/contravariance in Generics here:  http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/08/GenericVariance

Comment: +50 for generic method (if I could). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A `List<CardHolder>` is a `IEnumerable<CardHolder>`, but a `IEnumerable<CardHolder>` is not a `IEnumerable<ICardHolder>`. The two interfaces are unrelated (except for their structure).

C# 4.0 introduces covariance and contravariance, which can solve this kind of problem

Meanwhile, In C# 3.0, you can do :

```
deck.Deal(players.Cast<ICardHolder>());
```

It should have no significant performance impact, since the collection is only enumerated once, and the upcast to `ICardHolder` is a no-op in MSIL

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Ben's answer, you should replace the line:

```
    List<CardHolder> players = new List<CardHolder>();
```

with:

```
    List<ICardHolder> players = new List<ICardHolder>();
```

You're better off with interfaces anyway... :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work with the rest of the code I have, as it need to access some specific properties of CardHolder that ICardHolder doesn't (and cannot) have. But thanks anyway.

Comment: for CardHolder specific properties, you can always cast to CardHolder...