# Why can't I pass a List<List<Foo>> to an IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Foo>>

Tags: c#, generics, .net-3.5

This code generates two compile time errors:

```
private void DoSomething()
{
    List<List<Foo>> myFoos = GetFoos();

    UseFoos(myFoos);
}

private void UseFoos(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Foo>>)
{

}
```

`The best overloaded method match for 'NameSpace.Class.UseFoos(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Foo>>)' has some invalid arguments`

and

`Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<Foo>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Foo>>'`

Casting to `IEnumberable<List<Foo>>` isn't a problem.  What's different about casting the inner `List` component of the type that it fails?

Comment: Are you pre-C# 4.0? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280332/some-issues-with-sending-listt-as-ienumerablet-to-a-method and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730401/upcasting-and-generic-lists may be relevant, if not exact dupes.

Comment: Are you sure you're using C# 4.0?

Comment: @AakashM:  Correct I'm using 3.5.

Comment: @AakashM Looking at the 3.5 workarounds in those examples; unless/until I actually need to support the inner container being something other than a `List<>` I think I'll pass.  The implementations all fall the uglyness and obviousness checks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

EDIT: I've just realized that I haven't really answered the aspect of how to work around the limitation. Fortunately it's quite easy:

```
UseFoos(myFoos.Cast<IEnumerable<Foo>>());
```

---

That code compiles fine (when you've given the `UseFoos` parameter a name) under C# 4, which introduced *generic covariance and contravariance* for interfaces and delegates.

As a simpler example, this works in C# 4 but not in C# 3:

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = new List<string>();
IEnumerable<object> objects = strings;
```

Note that even in C# 4, classes aren't invariant, so this won't work:

```
// This won't work
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
List<object> objects = strings;
```

... and even for interfaces, it's only supported when it's safe:

```
// This won't work either
IList<string> strings = new List<string>();
IList<object> objects = strings;
```

The interface (or delegate) has to declare the variance of the type parameter itself, so if you look at the .NET 4 [documentation for `IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) you'll see it's declared as

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T>
```

where `out` declares the covariance in `T`.

Eric Lippert has a *lot* more about this in his blog category of [covariance and contravariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/).